# Why does the color editor in Blend stop working?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, blend

Right after starting Blend, the color editor works. But after a while, a yellow frame appears around the editor and it stops responding to the mouse.

In the Windows class

[image: 1]

In the resource dictionary

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

What the problem is connected with, I found out. It turns out that the editor stops working when the designer has disabled the project code. The right button in the screenshot. But the reason for this behavior is not clear.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSWTz.png